# Horizontal Scrollbar Controls Instead Of Bullet Controls For Glidejs

Tags: glidejs

Does [Glide](https://glidejs.com/) allow for a horizontal scroll bar as [the control UI](https://glidejs.com/docs/components/controls/) for sliding through images? Right now I only see [button controls](https://glidejs.com/docs/components/controls/), where each button maps to a slide.

Just to be clear I am still definitely interested in swiping behavior of course. I'd just like the button controls to behave like a scroll as well.

If Glide indeed allows for horizontal scrolling for controls can someone share how they implemented this? I cannot seem to find any guidelines in the docs.

Comment: Did you manage to find a way to implement this?

Comment: @AAlferez I did not with Glidejs. But with Swiperjs I believe its possible using https://stackblitz.com/run?file=index.html -- all you have to do is pass `draggable: true` into the swiper js scrollbar config. Here is the API https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#scrollbar